# Uglification failed. Unexpected character '`'

Tags: gulp, gulp-uglify, tvml, tvjs

gulp-uglify is unable to uglify this piece of code:

```
    var alertString = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
        <document>
          <alertTemplate>
            <title>${title}</title>
            <description>${description}</description>
          </alertTemplate>
        </document>`
```

it complains at the character: `. The character is valid for the apple's JS framework. 
I can't see anything inside the uglify package to ignore those characters and the text string inside it. Am i missing something from the documentation?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Gulp-uglify has yet no official support for ECMAScript 2015 (aka ES6, aka Harmony) but with a little modification the on-development repository can be used.

How-to:

1. Open Console and enter

`cd node_modules/gulp-uglify`

2. Edit package.json

`dependencies": {
   "uglify-js": "git+https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2.git#harmony" 
},`

3. Console enter:

`npm update`

And it is ready to run `.pipe(uglify())` again

---

**Alternate Solution**

1. Download the following via `npm`:

`npm install --save-dev gulp-uglify gulp-babel babel-preset-es2015`

2. Add the following requires in the `gulpfile.js`:

`var babel = require('gulp-babel'),
     uglify = require('gulp-uglify');`

3. The gulp task will be as follow:

`gulp.task('uglify', function(){
  gulp.src('*.js')
    .pipe(babel({
        presets: ['es2015']
    }))
    .pipe(uglify().on('error', function(e){
        console.log(e);
     }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js'));
});`

What this does is transpile all the EcmaScript 2015 JS code to EcmaScript5 and then uglifies it.

Comment: this is a gulp solution and your question starts with grunt. Did you switch to gulp?

Comment: @JonHarding Oh, yes. I completely overlooked it. Thank you for pointing it out. When I switched to gulp I had the same issue, but it was easier to find a solution. I'll edit the answer since I had the same issue with gulp

Answer (score 2):

ES6 is supported in a newer version of gulp-uglify called [gulp-uglify-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify-es). If you are using Gulp 4 you can also use .browserlistrc. Below are examples of a project I am using that needs Chrome and Firefox 56 support.

gulpfile.js

```
    const uglify = require('gulp-uglify-es').default;

    .pipe(babel({
        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
        compact:false
     }))
     .pipe(uglify())
```

.browserlistrc ([read more on browserlist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist))

```
last 2 chrome versions
firefox 56
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Flask + Jinja2 I've solved similar problem as following:

1. **Flask**

   render_template('template.html', text='"+`Text\nhere`+"')
2. **Apply uglify** ...
3. **JS**

   var result = "{{text}}";  // ---> "" + `Text\nhere` + "";